Loop in function keeps running after route changes (nextjs 14)
I have a component that is basically a file uploader, but it is meant for big files (like 10/20gb), I divide it in chunks, and have a while loop to send each chunk to my server.
I have a button in the same page (different component though) that redirects to a different page, using router.push, where router is from useRouter (next/navigation).
The problem is that if I have a file being uploaded and I click on the button, I get redirected to the other page correctly but I see the requests from the loop are still happening.
I know I can solve it by redirecting using window.location.href but I want to know if there's anyway this can be done using the router, not needing to fully load the new page.
Any ideas of a possible fix? Thank you!
